# Is it possible to slowly hide a component in reactjs? something like fadeout?

Tags: reactjs

I had to show a success message after a server operation, such as a successful deletion or edit.
now, what i did was to change state of 'show' to true and then after 2 seconds I change the state to false and the component gets hidden.
the problem is that it looks very sudden and I want to slow it down a bit, so it feels like it is fading out.

So, how does one do that in react?
example code of what I am doing

```
this.state.showAlert?<Alert message="success" />:''
```

how do I make this process a little slower?

Comment: for others who might come upon this.
I was using antdesign framework and thus had to use rc-animate the animation library that comes with it otherwise the accepted answer works for general react applications.
I was pointed in the right direction and that's why I accepted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) for this type of need